# Positioning block elements with CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to get a layout more or less like the following, but with fixed width's for the 'a' links:
http://jsfiddle.net/9SnJQ/

I can specify a fixed width by changing the 'a' links to block elements, but then I end up with this layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fh943/

How can I get the best of both (the correct positioning with fixed widths)?

Comment: have you tried `display: inline-block;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block;` for your `a` tags. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/9SnJQ/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Few comments at the beginning:

1. You should not use *. The way how CSS is being parsed is from RIGHT to LEFT. It means, that browser first checks the last condition, in this case *, which is EVERY ELEMENT ON THE PAGE and then it checks previous condition etc. This is the most INEFECTIVE selector you can use. Avoid it by all cost!
2. People are suggesting using inline-block. This will not work in IE7 and is not necessary

Ok, here is the way how I have made it - [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fh943/2/)